# Android: gradient in border of button

Tags: android, button, border, gradient

I am trying to create a button border style like this:
[image]

So I have created a drawable.xml and put 2 rectangular shapes on top of each other with the second one 2dp smaller like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="135"
                android:endColor="#6cd0f4"
                android:startColor="#acd44d"
                android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#4267af" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This work fine but I want to make the button transparent so it takes the color of its parent view.
Anyone have an idea how can I create a similar effect? Is nine-patch drawable more flexible to do such a job?

Comment: you can set Color as transparent

Comment: this will show up the first shape(the gradient)

Comment: create two view parent is ViewGroup and child is View then apply layer list on child view also set background of parent view. Might be It will work

Comment: you want button should be transparent  or gradiant ?

Comment: i want a button with gradient in border only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finilly decided to use nine patch images.

Answer (score 0):

Add #80 in the beginning of your hash code.

```
android:color="#804267af"
```

The 80 in the beginning is the value of transparency. 
Edited: the following are the values for the transparency, insert the two characters at the beginning of the hex for required percentage.

```
100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5%  — 0D

0% —  00
```

you can also use the following background attribute,

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

But you cannot explicitly give any required percentage values here.

Another way of doing it through your code is manually setting the alpha value of the color of the element.

```
yourButton.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I edited the answer with few more values to check. Try them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two rectangular view you can create view like this. I hope it will helpful for you for an example given below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#4178AA"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/xxxxx"
        android:background="@drawable/test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

test is your rectangular view.This will give you same shape as you added in question